# Can resource forks contain directories themselves?

Tags: filesystem, resources

I am trying to understand the semantics of resource forks and so far it seems that they largely overlap with NTFS alternate data streams, although differing it details. For example the resource entries seem to correspond to individual ADSs in NTFS, except that HFS+ can have multiple forks, adding one more dimension to data and resource fork.

However, I have two questions:

1. can a directory contain a resource fork? As per the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork) I would assume that *no* they can't, but I'd like this confirmed by someone who has more insight than that article.
2. can a resource fork itself contain directory structures?

When looking at this part of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork#Editing_resource_forks) it appears as if resource forks can contain directories themselves. However, I may be misreading it.

> In macOS, forks are named `file/..namedfork/forkname`, e.g., the
>   resource fork of the file `IMG_0593.jpg` is
>   `IMG_0593.jpg/..namedfork/rsrc`. The `ls` command supports a `-l@`
>   option which lists a file's forks.